# _Field table in progress 4GL database

Tags: rdbms, progress-4gl, openedge

Which is the field in this table which will give information of table to which field of _field belongs. for example say _Field is having one record with _field-name = 'XYZ', how can i identify to which table this XYZ field belongs?

Answer (score 7):

The RecordID (RECID) of the _file table is stored in a field in the _filed table.

```
FOR EACH _file NO-LOCK, EACH _field NO-LOCK WHERE _field._file-recid = RECID(_file):

    DISPLAY _file._file-name _field._field-name.
END.
```

Or utilize the primary index in the query using the "OF" operator:

```
FOR EACH _file NO-LOCK, EACH _field NO-LOCK OF _file:

    DISPLAY _file._file-name _field._field-name.
END.
```

Answer (score 2):

It is linked to the _File table through the _File-recid field.